# PyPDF hyperlink

Tags: python, pypdf

Is there a way to add a hyperlink in a PDF?

For example:

```
url = "https://www.google.com/"

# This cell should be a hyperlink to google
pdf.cell(20, 30, "This text redirects to google", 0, 0, 'C')
```

I found add_link & set_link in the [documentation](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ReferenceManual/index.html) but this only works as an internal link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Hello World!',link ="https://www.google.com")

pdf.output('tuto1.pdf', 'F')
```

Click on "Hello World" to jump to google.

You may have noticed the color of the text is still black. You can adjust the color by specifying the parameters in `set_font`